# Multiple recursive calls inside if/else statements and tail recursion

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I hope this question is not a dupe. It seems most questions refer to multiple recursive calls in one statement, ie.:`return func(n - 1) * func(n - 2)`. My question involves multiple recursive calls inside an `if/else` statement. THis is what I have (from doing a Project Euler problem):

```scala
def multOfThreeAndFive(n: Double): Double = {
  def loop(next: Double, acc: Double): Double = {
    if (next < 0) acc
    else if (next % 3 == 0 || next % 5 == 0) loop(next - 1, acc + next)
    else loop(next - 1, acc)
  }
  loop(n - 1, 0)
}
```

My question is, since I'm making two separate recursive calls, one inside `else if` and the other inside the last `else`, is this still considered tail recursive?

Comment: You mean you hope it is a dupe, so you'll have lots of vetted answers at your fingertips.  Except that if it's a dupe, they'll close it even if the other question is outdated or incomplete.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many instances you have of recursion; what matters is whether your code requires that anything be done after any recursive call.  In your example, each recursive call is a final step, so you're cool.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to check by yourself with special annotation. Compilation will fail if compiler isn't able to optimize code down to tail-recursion emulation:

```
def multOfThreeAndFive(n: Double): Double = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(next: Double, acc: Double): Double = {
    if (next < 0) acc
    else if (next % 3 == 0 || next % 5 == 0) loop(next - 1, acc + next)
    else loop(next - 1, acc)
  }
  loop(n - 1, 0)
}
```

And yes, it is considered as a tail recursive function.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I didn't considered `@annotation.tailrec` as a check. This will be useful while learning, specially because Eclipse doesn't tell you when something is tail recursive in the same IDEA does with a little loop icon.